# necessary condition for subspace of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Currently I'm reading linear algebra books by Leon and Friedberg.
In Friedberg's book, to be a subspace, a subset of a vector space should
(1). contain zero vector,
(2). be closed under scalar multiplication and
(3). be closed under vector addition.

But condition (1) is missing in Leon's book.

I think (1) is not necessary since if (2) and (3) holds, then (1) must be true.

Is (1) necessary?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does leon's book include "nonempty" in the definition of a subspace? Condition (1) can be replaced by the condition "the subset is nonempty".

Comment: Yes leon's definition include 'nonempty' thing. Thanks Adam and bof.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably it depends on your definition of vector space (i.e.: do you consider $\emptyset$ to be a vector space?) In my opinion, $\emptyset$ is should **not** be considered a vector space for various reasons, e.g. the fact that $\operatorname{span}\emptyset=\{0\}$, and thus point (1) should be included in the axioms for vector subspaces.

Comment: I didn't think of empty set. thanks Daniel Robert-Nicoud.

Answer (score 0):

Leon says that a *nonempty* subset that is closed under scalar multiplication and vector addition is a subspace. It turns out that you can prove that any nonempty subset of a vector space that is closed under scalar multiplication and vector addition always has to contain the zero vector.

*Hint:* What is zero times a vector? Now use closure under scalar multiplication.