# Prove that $\ker(T)$ of $T:V \rightarrow W$ is a subset of V

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I understand how $\ker(T)$ would be a subspace of $V$ from the following post
[Proof that a Kernel of a Linear Mapping is a Subspace](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2025958/proof-that-a-kernel-of-a-linear-mapping-is-a-subspace)

But how do we know that vectors in $\ker(T)$ would be in $V$ in the first place? Why is that a valid assumption?

Comment: I don't understand, why you went so far to see whether $\ker T$ is subspace or not, when you don't know the definition of $\ker T$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the definition of the kernel. $\ker(T)$ is defined as the set of vectors in $V$ that map to the zero vector in $W$, or equivalently:

$$\ker(T)=\{\mathbf{v}\in V|T(\mathbf{v})=\mathbf{0}\}$$

T is a linear transformation and is just a function that maps from $V$ to $W$, that fulfills the following conditions:
$$T(u+v)=T(u)+t(v)$$,
$$T(av)=aT(v)$$
$$ T(0)=0$$. That linear transformation can be represented as matrix $A$ by defining the following functions:
$$G^{-1}:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow V$$
$$H:W\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$$
Thus, our matrix $A$ can be written as:
$$HTG^{-1}=A$$
By applying those functions to our basis vectors of $V$ you can write out the matrix $A$ where the columns of that matrix are the functions applied to each basis vector.

Comment: So if we put it in matrix multiplication form $Ax=0,  A=ker(T), x \in V, 0 \in W$, but what forms T in the first place? are all columns of T vectors in V?

Comment: I answered  your question above